# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end - No clue where my code is wrong

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

This my code, and it is giving me an unexpected $end error and I cant seem to figure out why it is.

I thought it could have been because of the included files, but I get the same error running the code keeping the require files lines commented.
It says the error is on the last line.

```
<?php

//mysql and functions


require ("dbconnect.php");
require ("functions.php");

//start session
session_start();
//authenticate session - PART I
if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    echo "Please login.. Redirecting";
    header("refresh:2;url=login.php");
    die();
}
else
{
    //session data
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
    //check session data in database for second authentication
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND 
        firstname='$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(is_resource($check) and mysql_num_rows($check)>0)
    {
        //success
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Session Expired. Login Again.";
        header("refresh:2;url=login.php");
        die();
    }
    echo "Hi, This is protected content that is only for logged in members.";
?>
```

Comment: Use indentation and you will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's not visible from my earlier re-indentation, you're missing a `}` at the end, concluding the `else`.

Comment: Sigh! Sorry for missing that out, but I thought my IDE would say there is a missing tag. It didnt.

Thanks a ton Joachim.